# (clang++) Symbol not found from libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib

Tags: xcode, matlab, libstdc++

I meet an error called "Symbol not found" on matlab. The error message is in below.

```
Symbol not found: __ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
Referenced from: blabla/lib/buildW.mexmaci64
Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
```

There are quite bunch of questions like me, but I never found the solution of this problem. The former threads mentioned conflicts between the updated clang and the clang used.

Here are exmaples of questions on the similar question.

1. [Need help finding Undefined Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509847/need-help-finding-undefined-symbols)
2. [Handling "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found" error when nm does not find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541706/handling-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-error-when-nm-does)
3. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/4902

I currently installed Xcode 9.2.

And in matlab, I use MacOSX10.13.sdk like below.

```
>> edit ([matlabroot '/bin/maci64/mexopts/clang++_maci64.xml'])

...
...
<dirExists name="$$/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk" />             
<cmdReturns name="find $$ -name MacOSX10.13.sdk" />
```

Also, I found that there are three files in "/usr/lib"

```
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct version of `clang`? Recently XCode changed the location of its compiler tools, you might have an old version still on your system and still being used.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol `__ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv` (demangled `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const`) is defined in `libstdc++.dylib` but if you execute

```
nm /usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib | fgrep __ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
```

you will get

```
0000000000006a14 t __ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
```

as result. The `t` means that it's defined in the TEXT section but it's a *local* symbol which cannot referenced from outside the library.

Clang in Xcode uses

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.tbd
```

for linking instead of `/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib`. This is a human readable file which contains only the name of the public symbols in `libstdc++.dylib`. Since the symbol above is private it is not listed in the .tbd file.